# 'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push' RuntimeError: No application found

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

Before claiming this is a duplicate, I have searched through countless errors and I have not been able to find a solution that works for me.

I have a flask web application that I am sql alchemy to facilitate the connection with my google sql database. I need to create the tables corresponding to my application upon creating my application using the db.create_all() function. However, every-time I do so I get the error: "'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push'
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context"

Here is the code that I currently have. I would appreciate any help you would be able to offer:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)

  app.config.from_object(config)

  db.init_app(app)

  login_manager = LoginManager()
  login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
  login_manager.init_app(app)

  from .models import User

  @login_manager.user_loader
  def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

  from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
  app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

  from .main import main as main_blueprint
  app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

  with app.app_context():
      db.create_all()

  return app
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```py
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

with

```py
app.app_context().push()
db.create_all()
```

For more info refer to the [flask_sqlalchemy contexts docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts/).

By the way, you're using a newly created `SQLAlchemy` class that doesn't know which structure has to apply to the new DB. You should use the db object created with your models `from .models import User, db`.